# Modify/view static variables while debugging in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, variables, static

As per the question.
In the debug view, there's the Variables frame. It shows all the values of member variables of the current object, and all of the local variables, but it doesn't show any static variables of the object's class.

How do I get to these?

Some googling has suggested I press the button on the toolbar, but there's nothing on the Variables frame's toolbar except "Show Type Names" "Logical Structure" and "Collapse All" (Eclipse 3.4.2).

Any advice?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

In the Debug Variables view their is a arrow button in the right of the view. the tooltip of this button is `Menu`.

When you click this button a drop down menu is shown where you can select

`Java` -> `Show static variables`

Note: You do not have to restart Eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Simply put your mouse cursor over the static variable in the code and you will see the assigned value.

Answer (score 4):

You can view static variable and also edit during runtime. Click on small arrow pointing downword. see below image
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Window` -> `Show View` -> `Other` -> `Debug` -> `Expressions` -> Right Click on Window -> `Add Watch Expression...` -> Enter the name of the variable you want to see

Answer (score 1):

You might also try writing the expression e.g. self::$value in the watch window