# Eclipse debugger issues with variable display

Tags: java, eclipse

In my java eclipse debugger the variables field is always empty and the step over and step into icons are disabled  help me with this issues
I did try all the options from google like adding checking variables attributes in preferences menu but am still unable to find a solution help me friends

Comment: Should I install eclipse again to set right my eclipse debugger

Comment: I tried with various codes that worked well for others and also in tutorials it worked well

Comment: already an answer here - eclipse-debug-mode-variables-not-showing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490509/eclipse-debug-mode-variables-not-showing  . It tell you to reset your persepective and other options such as Window --> Show View --> Variables. Try it out, and please check existing answers in SO before posting a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a issue that is faced sometimes, somethings you might try out are:-

**->** Close variable window and open again

**->** Reset the perspective and see if variables now show up.

**->** Close the variables tab and then reset the perspective, this should reopen the working variables tab.

**->** If none of them still works , you can right click on the variable and select inspect, then it should come up in a popup window

Incase you do not know how to show vairables view, `Window --> Show View --> Variables`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490509/eclipse-debug-mode-variables-not-showing)

Comment: Okay l try the clicking inspect as I'am done with other steps

Comment: good to help, However we should instead suggest this as duplicate and provide the actual SO thread as link in comments, rather than posting a portion of it as answer.

Comment: Many answers on SO refer to other answers. Its a problem when you dont post a reference to the original question.  Also the question might not be duplicate since the one referenced uses version Galileo(in this case user has not mentioned any version) and also has no mention of disabling of `step into/step over` items

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the value of variables, you have to set a breakpoint.

See the documentation here: [EclipseDebugging](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html#prerequisites)

If you already set it, try **resetting the perspective**