# Eclipse debugger variables don't show name, only values

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

[image]Please the the attached snapshot. In my debugger, I can only see the variable values, but no names. It's very annoying. what might cause this?

Comment: Are you inside your own code?

Comment: what do you mean? I think yes. it is .

Comment: which OS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I tried everything found in the link that jotadepicas provided. It might be a combination of all those suggestions that lead up to me resolving the variable names not showing.

After trying all of the suggestions, I clicked on the down arrow in debug variables tab --> Layout --> Select Columns. Both the Name and Value boxes were already checked. I simply clicked OK and the Name column displayed. This Select Columns and Show Columns under Layout were not available prior to all the previous steps.

I am running Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 on Linux Mint 17.3.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reseting the Perspective, closing and opening de variables view again, even restarting eclipse. Have a look at this similar question just in case: [Eclipse Debug Mode: Variables not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490509/eclipse-debug-mode-variables-not-showing)

Answer (score 0):

It's a rendering problem in eclipse. click on the Variables Tab -> click on the vertically three dots icon appearing in the corner-> Layout - > Select columns -> Deselect all columns -> apply -> go back and select all columns .

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the debug symbol in the upper right window, (near the button to close the whole eclipse program) click on reset and then again on reset prospective.

End

Comment: This will reset the entire perspective to default settings, however.