# Eclipse Variables view not showing "Name" column

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Today while debugging an app, my Variables view stopped displaying the "Name" column and shows only "Value". I also observed the Variables view briefly blank after a reset of the perspective. This latter problem was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490509/eclipse-debug-mode-variables-not-showing), but I cannot find a solution to the "Name" column disappearing. I have tried restarting Eclipse, resetting the (Debug) perspective, closing and opening the perspective, and closing and opening a new Variables tab, but no luck. Running Eclipse Mars w/ CDT on Ubuntu 14.04. The last software update was two days ago, and Eclipse was running fine yesterday, so likely not due to any updates. Any ideas how to restore the column?

Edit: [SOLVED] I located the pulldown menu in the Variables view (Layout->Select Columns). Even though "Name", "Value", and "Type" were selected, I went ahead and deselected all, then reselected all and now everything is visible.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but are you sure the column is not simply of zero width? If you move your mouse right next to the value column does it show the resize pointer?

Comment: There is also a small triangle in the top right corner of the view. When pressed you can select Layout -> Select columns... and verify that "name" is checked