# How to track value of a variable in Eclipse Java Debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I would like to track the value of a boolean (not Boolean) variable in the Eclipse debugger.

I need to know when it does change and, for this, i need to track it's value through all the execution; not only when it is in scope.

More particularly: I have a class (let's call it `myClass`) with a boolean member variable called `isAvailable`. My program instantiate 4 or 5 `myClass` objects. I am expecting that at the end of the execution the `isAvailable` value of all of my objects is set to `true`. Contrarily to my excpectation one of `myClass` objects has `isAvailable` set to false. I need to know which (in a lot of) methods is setting `isAvailable` to false.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801193/modify-view-static-variables-while-debugging-in-eclipse

Answer (score 4):

You can set a watchpoint on the member field. A watchpoint is like a breakpoint that suspends execution when the field is either accessed or modified (you can configure which conditions you want to stop at). See http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html#advanced_watchpoint

Comment: You cannot configure which conditions you want to stop at.

Comment: @mjaggard, yes you can. Create a Watch Point, select it in the Breakpints view, and there you see checkboxes for stopping at Access and Modification. Select which conditions you want to stop at.

Comment: Where can I select to stop when this variable equals 7? http://i.imgur.com/Wl6j1DH.png

Answer (score 3):

Do you have access to the code the class is in?

Instead of using the variable use setters and getters to access it, then just put a break point on the setter.

IF you just need to know when it changes put a conditional break point and have the expression be something like:

```
available != this.available
```

Assuming your setter is of the following format:

```
public void setAvailable(boolean available){
    this.available = available;
}
```

You can get a conditional break point by right clicking on the break point symbol once you've set a break point.

Here is an FAQ about conditional break points:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F

Comment: Well, i thought that could be a good way, but i didn't write the code (i'm only bug fixing) and it is a huge project with lots and lots of classes so before spending hours editing the code i would try something more automatic!

Comment: No code modification is required to set up a breakpoint, just access to the source code...

Comment: The Setter gived you a single point of access, you can set a conditional breakpoint on every line of code that accesses the variable if you can't edit the code. However if lots of other classes are accessing a raw variable without a setter then your code suffers from tight coupling and should probably be re-factored to use a setter/getter anyway.

Comment: thank all of you for your answers. I have access to the code but there is no setter in the class for isAvailable. So, before adding a setter and change every class that accesses the variable or adding breakpoints in every method that accesses the variable, I will try something different... if nothing works i will try to follow your suggestions and will let you know how  it goes!

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint in the method that sets the value for `isAvailable`.

When the breakpoint is hit, you'll have the possibility to check the whole execution stack. You will also be able to inspect the object and determine which of the 4 or 5 instances is concerned.

Comment: How do we do that in android studio